# what am i able to use for design work from bambi film?

Tags: copyright

I am looking for some advice?

I am doing disney inspired designs so more of a deconstructed version, but in the design I am looking to use some butterflies, birds and squirrel which has been seen in the film to help people make the connection.

I have searched everywhere but could not find if those generic animals are protected so could be used by me?

I am based in the U.K so outside the USA.

looking for some advice asap

thanks

Answer (score 1):

All of the artwork in the movie is protected by copyright, which means you must obtain permission from the copyright holder. The matter is mildly obscured by two facts. First, the movie was based on an earlier German book and was adapted without permission. For a while, this was okay because of details of German copyright law, then the US 9th Circuit court decided in [Twin Books Corp. v. Walt Disney Co](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-9th-circuit/1304377.html)., 83 F.3d 1162 that the original work did not fall into the public domain in the US. However, the artwork in the movie was indisputably created by Disney in 1942. Then the question would be whether copyright protection has lapsed. The [rules for duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States#Duration_of_copyright) of protection of works created before 1978 are complex, but under the circumstance that Disney followed the rules for publication and registration, copyright expires in 2037. You should hire an attorney to advise you as to whether Disney is likely to legally pursue an infringement lawsuit, but informally speaking, they are very strict about their copyright.